# How to run custom method when parent model updated after touch()

Tags: php, laravel

There are two models City and Street

```
class City extends Model {
    public function streets() {
        return $this->hasMany(Street::class);
    }
}  

class Street extends Model  {
    protected $touches = ['city'];

    public function city() {
        return $this->hasOne(City::class);
    }
}
```

If I update `Street` model then `City->updated_at` changed too

How I can to run custom method when `City` model is updating after `Street` model changed?

Overriding `touch()` method in `City` model don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside model you can add this boot function to add some custom code inside the updated event

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updated(function ($var) {
        // Run you custom code
    });
}
```

Comment: thx for fast answer, I tried your solition. But it work if i update `City` model directly, and don't work if I update `Street` model, although `City->updated_at` changed.

Comment: I add this code in `Steet` model and run `$var->city->touch()` there. Accordingly I override `touch()` method in `City` model where I using my custom code. It's work.